# Strange SNMP shifting operation

Tags: c#, .net, snmp

The following is from the book C# Network Programmingm by Richard Blum:

```
public byte[] get(string request, string host, string community, string_ mibstring)
{
    byte[] packet = new byte[1024];
    byte[] mib = new byte[1024];
    int snmplen;
    int comlen = community.Length;
    string[] mibvals = mibstring.Split('.');
    int miblen = mibvals.Length;
    int cnt = 0, temp, i;
    int orgmiblen = miblen;
    int pos = 0;
    // Convert the string MIB into a byte array of integer values
    // Unfortunately, values over 128 require multiple bytes
    // which also increases the MIB length
    for (i = 0; i < orgmiblen; i++)
    {
        temp = Convert.ToInt16(mibvals[i]);
        if (temp > 127)
        {
            mib[cnt] = Convert.ToByte(128 + (temp / 128));
            mib[cnt + 1] = Convert.ToByte(temp - ((temp / 128) * 128));
            cnt += 2;
            miblen++;
        } 
        else
        {
        mib[cnt] = Convert.ToByte(temp);
        cnt++;
        }
    }
    snmplen = 29 + comlen + miblen - 1; //Length of entire SNMP packet
    //The SNMP sequence start
    packet[pos++] = 0x30; //Sequence start
    packet[pos++] = Convert.ToByte(snmplen - 2); //sequence size
    //SNMP version
    packet[pos++] = 0x02; //Integer type
    packet[pos++] = 0x01; //length
    packet[pos++] = 0x00; //SNMP version 1
    //Community name
    packet[pos++] = 0x04; // String type
    packet[pos++] = Convert.ToByte(comlen); //length
    //Convert community name to byte array
    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(community);
    for (i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        packet[pos++] = data[i];
    }
}
```

I didn't understand the following code:

```
    for (i = 0; i < orgmiblen; i++)
    {
        temp = Convert.ToInt16(mibvals[i]);
        if (temp > 127)
        {
            mib[cnt] = Convert.ToByte(128 + (temp / 128));
             mib[cnt + 1] = Convert.ToByte(temp - ((temp / 128) * 128));
             cnt += 2;
             miblen++;
        } 
        else
        {
            mib[cnt] = Convert.ToByte(temp);
            cnt++;
        }
    }
```

I do understand this is for putting down into two bytes if the temp is larger then one byte. But what is the calculation being done 128+(temp/128) and then for the second byte: temp- (temp/128)*128, this is what i don't understand.

Please help, Thank you.

Comment: why upvote? care to explain?

Comment: That certainly isn't a standard conversion from int to bytes. It must be something specific to the SNMP protocol. Or simple nonsense. It looks pretty strange for two reasons: (1) A byte can hold values up to 255. Why everything above *127* (and not 128 as the comment says) needs special treatment is unclear. (2) Splitting an integer into its byte parts usually is done using bit shifting operations. (3) Even if the reason for this splitting would be that the protocol only supports signed bytes with a range from -128 to 127, the conversion makes no sense, because it will result (cont)

Comment: (cont) in values bigger than 127 in the first byte (see example calculation by Eoin Campbell)

Comment: @Voice: a) Because the question is well written. He have included a complete code so that you can get the picture, then the part he have a problem with and an explanation of what he do and do not understand. b) because the code use a wierd solution for shifting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is quoted from *Understanding SNMP MIBs* page 394, as this book describes the technical details better than any others,

> An encoded OBJECT IDENTIFIER consists of each sub-identifier in the original value encoded and concatenated. Each sub-identifier is encoded as a series of octets, which is as follows,
>
> - Bit 8 in each octet indicates if it is the last octet of the sub-identifier by setting this bit to 0
> - Bits 7 through 1 in the octets, when concatenated, form the value of the sub-identifier
> - The first octet in the sub-identifier may not have the value 80 (in HEX). This ensures that the smallest number of octets are used for the encoding. A value of 80 (in HEX) would indicate that more octets follow, but the value bits (7-1) are set to zero.

The pasted source code in the question body in fact follows the rules to parse the bytes. Thus, if you understand the rules, you can understand the code.

(Updated: The rules come from [ITU-T X.690, ISO/IEC 8825-1](http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.690-0207.pdf).)

Comment: Great help, I was just curious - I couldn't get that book anywhere so started searching on the internet and came across an engineering thesis where he describes the same in David Perkins words on page 12 of the document (pdf page 23): here is the link: http://etd.lib.fsu.edu/theses/available/etd-11102008-191830/unrestricted/VollmerDThesis.pdf. I'm glad people like you are out there to help. I now do understand that code completely and am working on my own solution.

Answer (score 3):

if temp is larger than 127, then it will be split across 2 bytes. lets look at 2 examples/

```
temp = 100;
128 + (temp / 128); //(temp / 128) = 0 + 128 so the mib[cnt] is set to 128
temp - ((temp/128) * 128); // 0*128 = 0. subtracted from temp leaves the original. so you end up with

mib[cnt] = 128;
mib[cnt+1] = 100;
```

Now if temp is > 127

```
temp = 200;
128 + (temp / 128); //(temp / 128) = 1 + 128 so the mib[cnt] is set to 129
temp - ((temp/128) * 128); // 1*128 = 128. 200-128 = 72. so you end up with

mib[cnt] = 129;
mib[cnt+1] = 72;
```

So basically, it's taking a number, testing if it's > 7 bytes (-128 => +127 is one signed byte) and if the number you've supplied would overflow that range, it converts it into a 2 byte value/

Comment: Can you explain how the two bytes *129* and *72* are supposed to represent *200*? Neither ANDing nor ORing will result in 200. Furthermore, 129 is still above the maximum value of 127 for a signed byte.

Comment: I assume it's something to do with the snmp protocol. 128 in binary = `1000 0000` but you can't stored 128 in a single byte as it would overflow. So I assume it's treating that most significant bit as a sign +/- value. int=100 evaluates to `1000 0000 0110 0100`. int=200 evaluates to `1000 0001 0100 1000`. So if you just throw away that left most significant digit, it evaluates as a 2-byte (word) value

Comment: Interpreting `1000 0001` as a signed byte results in `-127`. Adding 72 results in `-55`...

Comment: I agree. I'm not saying it makes sense. just that's what the code seems to be doing. I've no idea why he's toggling the left most significant bit in that way because as you point out, that would seem to negate the value.

Comment: If you happened to have *Understanding SNMP MIBs* book at hand, you can find the explanation on page 394 A.5.4. The toggled bit is used to indicate multi-octet sub-identifiers.

Comment: @LexLi: +1 for that. Thank you for that. I tried finding the book at the local book stores, but this seems to be rare here in my city. Is it possible you can share with me that page. I would be grateful, it would help me understand this better. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: @user726720 I just typed the paragraphs for your reference.

Answer (score -1):

This works with all values:

```
        for (i = 0; i < orgmiblen; i++)
        {
            temp = Convert.ToInt64(mibvals[i]);
            int k = (int)Math.Log((Double)temp, (Double)2) / 7;
            miblen += k;
            int continuation = 0;
            do
            {
                mib[cnt++ + k] = Convert.ToByte((temp & 127) + continuation);
                temp = ((int)(temp / 128));
                continuation = 128;
                k -= 2;
            }
            while (temp > 0);
        }
```

Comment: -1 you did not answer the question. He wanted to understand ***why*** the code looked like that.