# C# SNMP trap receiver

Tags: c#, .net, snmp

I need to trap SNMP and have done the following code, I'm getting the data correctly but the objectID is coming out garbled, is there any reason for this

```
       int port=162;
         UdpClient listener;
        IPEndPoint groupEP;
        byte[] packet = new byte[1024];
        int commlength, miblength, datatype, datalength, datastart, Objecttype, Objectlength;
        int objectstart;
        string objectid;

        string output;

        Console.WriteLine("Initializing SNMP Listener on Port:" + port + "...");

       // try
       // {
            listener = new UdpClient(port);
            groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for messages....");
                packet = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
                Console.WriteLine("Processing new message...");
                if (packet.Length != null)
                {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("New message from {0} :\n {1}\n", groupEP.ToString(), packet);
                if (packet[0] == 0xff)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Packet");
                    return;
                    }

                commlength = Convert.ToInt16(packet[6]);
               miblength = Convert.ToInt16(packet[10 + commlength]);

               Objecttype = Convert.ToInt16(packet[30 + commlength + miblength]);
                Objectlength = Convert.ToInt16(packet[31 + commlength + miblength]);
                objectstart = 32 + commlength + miblength;
                datatype = Convert.ToInt16(packet[26+ Objecttype + Objectlength+commlength+ miblength]);
                datalength = Convert.ToInt16(packet[27 + Objecttype + Objectlength + commlength + miblength]);
                datastart = 28 + Objecttype + Objectlength + commlength + miblength;
                    output = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(packet, datastart, datalength);
                    objectid = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(packet, objectstart , Objectlength);
                Console.WriteLine("sysLocation - Datatype: {0}, Value: {1}", datatype,output);
                Console.WriteLine(objectid);


                }


            }
```

The data is stored as string hex, would the objectid be stored the same way as it contains '.'
I know I can use existing libraries (freely available on the net), but I have just created myself an oppurtunity to learn.

Please advise.

Comment: This question is still open, I need help on this please

Comment: Have you read any related books, IETF RFC documents, or any other serious materials? The encoding methods for OID is obviously not as easy as you guess above, and by reading the proper materials you will see why. I have pasted some paragraphs from *Understanding SNMP MIBs* under this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270451/understanding-c-sharp-code

Comment: @LEXLI: great +1 for that. Thank you.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could share with me the IETF RFC documents that relate to SNMP OID's.

Comment: The SNMP rules for OBJECT IDENTIFIER originate from ITU-T X690, ISO/IEC 8825-1, http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.690-0207.pdf You can find the original standard document and read about how BER works.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at this ＳＮＭＰ lib 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/snmpsharpnet/files/ .

you do not have to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 2):

Example in C# and VB.Net with SnmpSharpNet.
[Click here](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/?page_id=117)

Answer (score 0):

Now in 2019 I would rather go for #SNMP since it's constantly developed based on [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lextm.SharpSnmpLib/) last date published. Has up-to-date [docs](https://docs.sharpsnmp.com/getting-started/index.html) and this neat [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/snmp-trap-listener-using-snmp-library/) which describes exactly what you want to achieve. It looks like it's [working with .NET Core](https://docs.sharpsnmp.com/support/platforms.html) as well.